# What I am I missing so that my Logic operator works properly for my if-else statement?

Tags: javascript

My if-else code block is running well except for the last condition where I use an AND logic operator. I'm new to JavaScript and I can't figure out where I am going wrong! Ideas?

I've tried adding brackets, taking away brackets, and rejigging the statement.

```js
//declare variables the prompts the user to state their birthdate in 
//month, day and year
var birthYear = prompt('What year were you born in?');
var birthMonth = prompt('What month were you born in? In numerals please!');
var birthDay = prompt('What day of the month were you born on? In numerals please!');

//declare variables to get current date
var now = new Date();
var currentYear = now.getFullYear();
var currentMonth = now.getMonth() + 1; //so now January = 1
var currentDay = now.getDate();
//declare variable for age will turn this year
var age = currentYear - birthYear;
//declare variable for text output
var text = "";
//create if/else loop for three different scenarios
if (birthMonth < currentMonth) {
  text += "You have turned " + age + " years old already this year.";
} else if (birthMonth > currentMonth) {
  text += "You will be turning " + age + " years old later this year.";
} else if (birthMonth === currentMonth && birthDay === currentDay) {
  text += "Today is your Birthday! Happy Birthday!";
}

document.getElementById('agestate').innerHTML = text;
```

```html
<p id="agestate"></p>
```

I should be able to input the current month and date when prompted to get the statement back "Today is your birthday. Happy Birthday!"

Comment: `prompt()` always returns a string. Use `var someNumber = Number(prompt("..."));` (also note that the code doesn't provide an answer if my birthday is in the current month but not today)

Answer (score 2):

Don't use strict equals (`===`). Standard `==` should work here, as your datatypes are incompatible: `birthMonth` is a string, and `currentMonth` is an integer, so strict equality will fail. Alternatively, you can convert the string to a number (or vise-versa) before comparing.

You can try the newly updated code below (Enter todays date to show "Today is your Birthday! in the prompts)

```js
//declare variables the prompts the user to state their birthdate in 
//month, day and year
var birthYear = prompt('What year were you born in?');
var birthMonth = prompt('What month were you born in? In numerals please!');
var birthDay = prompt('What day of the month were you born on? In numerals please!');

//declare variables to get current date
var now = new Date();
var currentYear = now.getFullYear();
var currentMonth = now.getMonth() + 1; //so now January = 1
var currentDay = now.getDate();
//declare variable for age will turn this year
var age = currentYear - birthYear;
//declare variable for text output
var text = "";

//create if/else loop for three different scenarios
if (birthMonth < currentMonth) {
    text += "You have turned " + age + " years old already this year.";
} else if (birthMonth > currentMonth) {
    text += "You will be turning " + age + " years old later this year.";
} else if (birthMonth == currentMonth && birthDay == currentDay) {
    text += "Today is your Birthday! Happy Birthday!";
}

console.log(text);
```

Comment: I would recommend to use number parsing instead of double equals, it kinda encourages to write code in the wonderful javascript pitfalls :)

Answer (score 1):

Building upon FrankerZ answer, the `prompt` function returns a string and not a number, however I discourage the use of `==` since it is one of javascript awful random behaviors, in any other (sane) language trying to compare strings and numbers would not compile or throw an error, but javascript has hidden behaviors with loose equality, you can read more about it [here](https://codeburst.io/javascript-double-equals-vs-triple-equals-61d4ce5a121a)

I encourage you to use number parsing and `===` instead (also handling missing case):

```
//declare variables the prompts the user to state their birthdate in 
//month, day and year
var birthYear = Number(prompt('What year were you born in?'));
var birthMonth = Number(prompt('What month were you born in? In numerals please!'));
var birthDay = Number(prompt('What day of the month were you born on? In numerals please!'));

//declare variables to get current date
var now = new Date();
var currentYear = now.getFullYear();
var currentMonth = now.getMonth() + 1; //so now January = 1
var currentDay = now.getDate();
//declare variable for age will turn this year
var age = currentYear - birthYear;
//declare variable for text output
var text = "";

//create if/else loop for three different scenarios
if (birthMonth < currentMonth) {
    text += "You have turned " + age + " years old already this year.";
} else if (birthMonth > currentMonth) {
    text += "You will be turning " + age + " years old later this year.";
} else if (birthMonth === currentMonth && birthDay === currentDay) {
    text += "Today is your Birthday! Happy Birthday!";
} else (birthMonth === currentMonth && birthDay !== currentDay) {
    text += "Your birthday is this month! Lucky you!";
}
```

Comment: added small explanation and link to a loose equality article